# Why don't pic prefixes in TikZ work with matrix cell names?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-matrix, tikz-node, tikz-pic

When I have a pic whose code includes a matrix, things don't work when I use a name prefix for the pic:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
test/.pic = {
\matrix (mat) [matrix of nodes, nodes in empty cells, column sep = 15 pt, ampersand replacement = \&, nodes = {draw}]{
  \&  \\
} ;
\draw (mat-1-1) -- (mat-1-2) ;
}]

\pic (pre-) {test} ;

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I get the error: `Package pgf Error: No shape named 'mat-1-1' is known.`

But when I don't use a prefix:

`\pic {test}`

I get the expected result:

[image]

I believe what's happening is that the matrix name `(mat)` gets prefixed to `(pre-mat)`, but for some reason the individual cell names like `(mat-1-1)` do **not** get prefixed to `(pre-mat-1-1)` as I would expect.

**Why doesn't the prefix get affixed to the matrix cell names?  And how do I fix it so that it works?**

Comment: Interesting, without a computer near me, I'd guess that the nodes inside the matrix might get named `pre-pre-mat-1-1`. Can you check by adding `name prefix ..` to the options of the matrix?

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel It appears you might be right. After adding name prefix .. it is working properly, and I am able to reference the various components outside the pic, like `pre-mat`, `pre-mat-1-1`, etc.  But I don't quite understand why this works.  Why would the cells get named `pre-pre-mat-1-1` in the first place?

Comment: Because the names of the nodes inside the matrix use the same naming algorithm as the matrix. The nodes' names get prefixed with the (prefixed) name of the matrix (stored in `\tikzmatrixname`). I don't have a good short fix for all possible use cases. Maybe `name prefix ..` or rather `name prefix=` is the best if you only have exactly one node automatically named inside a matrix. How does your real use-case look like? If it's just that, a matrix with connections between the cells, we don't really need a pic for that.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Okay I think I get it now.  Just thinking out loud - it looks like the rule is that every time a new node / named thing is encountered in the pic, the prefix `pre-` is attached to it.  So it names the matrix as `pre-mat`, then the matrix functionality generates individual nodes like `pre-mat-1-1`, but since this is the first time these nodes are generated / encountered,  the rule says they too must get prefixed with `pre-`, so we get `pre-pre-mat-1-1`, etc.  But...

Comment: putting `name prefix ..` temporarily sets the prefix back to its value outside the pic (nothing) while inside the matrix, so no extra prefix gets added to `pre-mat-1-1`.  Let me know if I'm getting any of this wrong.

Comment: I think you explained it even better. Which brings me to `\path[name prefix=Foo-]pic(Bar-){code={\matrix(Mat)[matrix of nodes]{{\csname tikz@fig@name\endcsname}\\};}};`. That leads to the matrix node to be named `Foo-Bar-Foo-Bar-Mat-1-1`, so using `name prefix=` is better than `name prefix ..`. A matrix really should use the same concept for names as a pic but it doesn't.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Would you mind writing an answer? This is actually a good solution!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a pic gets assigned a name, this name will be set as the [`name prefix`](https://tikz.dev/tikz-shapes#pgf./tikz/name:prefix) of its content. This makes it so that a node named `mat` inside a pic named `pre-` is actually named `pre-mat` and the name of this matrix will be stored in `\tikzmatrixname`.

However, with the `matrix of nodes` setup, each node gets assigned the name `\tikzmatrixname-\the\pgfmatrixcurrentrow-\the\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn` which usually gets you nicely named nodes. However, this uses the same naming mechanism as the matrix node so the `name prefix` setup by the pic will actually applied twice.

See the following example where the nodes are named `Foo-Bar-Foo-Bar-Mat-R-C`. (`\tikz@fig@name` is the internal macro for the node name.)

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}
\tikz
  \path[name prefix=Foo-]
    pic (Bar-) {                          % pic name: Foo-Bar-
      code={                              % → name prefix: Foo-bar-
        \matrix (Mat) [matrix of nodes] { % Matrix name: Foo-Bar-Mat
                                          % → \tikzmatrixname: Foo-Bar-Mat
          {\csname tikz@fig@name\endcsname}
          \\ % this gets converted to
          \node (\tikzmatrixname-\the\pgfmatrixcurrentrow
                                -\the\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn)
            {\csname tikz@fig@name\endcsname};
          \\
        };
      }
    };
\end{document}
```

Now, in my opinion, it would be better if a matrix uses the same naming mechanism as a pic, i.e. it sets up its own `name prefix`, but this is not easily adjusted.

In your case, the easiest approach is to use [`name prefix ..`](https://tikz.dev/tikz-pics#pgf./tikz/name:prefix:..) as an option to the matrix.

However, this will also reset the prefix for normal nodes that don't use `\tikzmatrixname`. So, a matrix with content `{|(a)| \& |(b)| \\}` will have nodes named `a` and `b`, not `pre-a`/`pre-b`.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  test/.pic = {
    \matrix (mat) [
      matrix of nodes,
      nodes in empty cells,
      column sep = 15pt,
      ampersand replacement = \&,
      nodes = draw,
      name prefix .. % ←
    ]{ \& \\};
    \draw (mat-1-1) -- (mat-1-2);
  }]
\pic (pre-) {test};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```